# MySQL multiple queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms

**Problem has been solved**

I have created a form that processes the changing of user information from the admin side e.g. the admin changes a user's username and/or email. I am having trouble processing multiple queries.

For example, if the admin changes the username, the query works. If the admin changes the email address, the query works. But if the admin changes the username and email at the same time through the form then only the username changes.

Any ideas? I will submit my code but I will change variables for security reasons etc. Also, anything in capitals has been changed for security reasons. The code is all correct for each individual function because as I said, if I ONLY change the email, it works and actually changes. But if I change the username AND email, only the username will change despite the fact the email query runs and it echo's the email has been changed!

**Also, it is worth noting that all of the fields e.g. username field and email field are part of one form that submits to one page.**

```
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT_BUTTON_PRESSED'])) {
//Gather all inputs from the form and sanitise it.
//REMOVED FOR SECURITY REASONS.

if($USERNAME_NEW != "") {
    if($USERNAME_NEW == $CURRENT_USERNAME) {
        echo "You have entered the username you are already using. Please enter a different username.";
    } else {
    $CHECK_USERNAME = "SELECT USERNAME_ROW FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE username='$USERNAME_NEW'";
    $RUN_QUERY = mysqli_query($CONNECTION INFO, $CHECK_USERNAME);
    $RESULT = mysqli_num_rows($RUN_QUERY);
    if($RESULT > 0) {
    echo "That username already exists. You cannot use that username again. Please enter another username.";    
    } else {
    $editing_username = true;
    $USERNAME = $NEW_USERNAME; //NOT NEEDED BUT IT STILL WORKS
    $THE_SQL_QUERY = "UPDATE USER_TABLE SET username='$USERNAME' WHERE username='$ORIGINAL USERNAME'";
    $RUN_THIS_QUERY= mysqli_query($CONNECTION INFO, $THE_SQL_QUERY);
    echo "The user's username has been changed to:  ". $USERNAME;
        }
    }
}
     if($EMAIL != "") {
        if($EMAIL == $CURRENT_EMAIL) {
            echo "You have entered the same email address to the one you are already using. Please enter a different email address.";
        } else {
            $CHECK_EMAIL = "SELECT USERS_EMAIL FROM USER_TABLE WHERE username='$USER'";
            $CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY = mysqli_query($CONNECTION_INFO, $CHECK_EMAIL);
            $RESULT = mysqli_num_rows($CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY);
            if($RESULT > 0) {
            echo "That email already exists. You cannot use that username again. Please enter another username.";   
            } else {
                $editing_email = true;
                $THE_NEW_EMAIL = $FINAL_EMAIL_THING; // AGAIN NOT NEEDED BUT STILL WORKS
                $THE_SQL= "UPDATE USER_TABLE SET USER_EMAIL='$EMAIL' WHERE username='$USER' LIMIT 1"; // REMOVED THE LIMIT 1, STILL DOESN'T WORK
                $RUN_THIS_QUERY = mysqli_query($CONNECTION, $THE_SQL);
                if($RUN_THIS_QUERY) {
                echo "The user's email has been changed."; // EVEN WHEN BOTH FIELDS ARE SUBMITTED THIS WORKS SO THE QUERY IS RUNNING BUT THE EMAIL DOESN'T CHANGE
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help! Also, no un-witty remarks about how my question is structured etc. because I don't care to be honest. I just want this code working to be honest because I've been working on it for a while. This may be something simple or I might be using the wrong approach for this type of form submission.

Remember: THIS CODE DOES WORK WHEN I SUBMIT EACH FIELD SEPARATELY!

Comment: Is it your real code? I like those variable names

Comment: @zerkms Nope... As I pointed out. I changed all important variables for security reasons. I don't want people knowing the real variables. Despite the fact the form and everything about my system is SQL injection-proof I still would rather people didn't know variable names and I'm sure you'd be the same.

Comment: "I changed all important variables for security reasons. I don't want people knowing the real variables" --- :-D You've made my day, thank you. "and I'm sure you'd be the same" --- of course not, I understand that what you've done has nothing to do with "security" at all.

Comment: @zerkms Am I missing something? How does that make your day? I like privacy. If that's your idea of a 'fun' day then you must be having a terrible day! xD

Comment: @A Sweaty Wombat: my day will be better tomorrow, your code will stay terrible forever ;-D

Comment: @zerkms Please be my guest and point out what's 'wrong' with my code? All data is sanitised, I'm using SQL functions properly, connections are closed where necessary, there are no functions that can cause hanging on the application. The code is extremely efficient.

Comment: @zerkms If you pretend you're an expert on PHP and MySQL please leave. I don't pretend to be an expert. I've enforced proper procedure on my code and that's all that matters. Indentation isn't perfect on here, it's better on Dreamweaver but still not perfect. If by some means I have used something incorrectly, as I said I'm no expert so point it out. I'm happy for my code to be scrutinised, but not by someone who knows no better.

Comment: @ASweatyWombat I think zerkms was trying to point out that '$RUN THIS QUERY' is not a valid variable name, as space separation would treat this as a variable $RUN then two unknown commands THIS and QUERY. Other than that, Why don't you go back to your HTML form, give the current value to the forms (as a default value), then you post the form, and perform an update that will set both email and username to the one in the text input fields?

Comment: i won't bother with this question as long as code has illegal variable names. sorry, my mind just produces errors when i see a variable like `$THE SQL QUERY `

Comment: @Alex As I pointed out to zerkms, those are not real variables. I removed them because I'm extremely concerned in terms of security so I removed all real variables. I know you can't have spaces but for the purpose of this, it really doesn't matter. The code fully works (the code I have, not this code) and I won't break and reveal real variables for anyone so if that's his game it's not a very good one.

Comment: @Sharky Why don't you read the whole question. I **CLEARLY** state that the variables are **NOT** the variables I use in my code. I know the variables in this question are illegal and don't work. Re-read the **WHOLE** question and think again.

Comment: @ASweatyWombat Why don't you read the whole comment. I **CLEARLY** state that illegal variables make my mind produces errors. I said SORRY i can't help it.

Comment: @Sharky I apologise for the tone in my reply. I am very tired of people saying that the variables are not valid when I have stated many times they are not the variables are the ones I use. I could not be bothered editing the code in such a way that all of the code variables were valid. Alex has kindly suggested an edit that I will approve when I can (for some reason I cannot approve the edit whilst on my Surface 2); his edit fixes these illegal variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very hard to figure out as you are not producing the real code.

I think you have missed something here.
As you are using USER_NAME as key in the SQL's, make sure that you are using the updated username in the second sets of SQL (to update the email) as they are already replaced by the first SQL.

And there is no security risk while showing your codes snippets to someone else. Hide only the username/passwords or Identities. :)

Comment: I have just realised the problem thanks to your reply. I have a username variable stored so the system know which user is being edited. Once I change the username that variable is wrong as it is the old username. I have been using the old variable for all of the other statements so it's trying to edit the email for a user that doesn't exist!

Comment: See comment above. I forgot to add your name in excitement of figuring out the problem.

Comment: Reading your answer fully I realise you explained the problem. Thank you.